# Flutter / Firebase Firestore : How to create a book tracking system?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app in Flutter where users can add some book chapters to their profile and read it.
Now I want to create a training system when the user has read a chapter, the app marks it as read.
I'm using Firebase Firestore like this [image: Firestore model]

I was thinking to add a "read" field in the chapter document but it will result in every user will have the mark "read" in the app.

So, how to create a tracking system that allows marking read chapters just for the current user?

Comment: What do those "chapters" represent? Magazines, books, or chapters of books, what exactly?

Comment: Those "chapters" represent the chapters of mangas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option that you have is to store all those chapters in an array in the user object:

```
$uid (document)
 |
 --- chapters: ["Cross Guild", "Other Cross Guild"]
```

Or in a Map:

```
$uid (document)
 |
 --- chapters (map)
       |
       --- Cross Guild: true
       |
       --- Other Cross Guild: true
```

> I will have 10.000 chapters.

If you're afraid about the [1 MiB maximum limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) of a document, then I recommend you create a document for the starting letter of a chapter:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- chapters (collection)
        |
        --- aChapters (document)
        |     |
        |     --- //Array or Map of chapters starting with the letter a.
        |
        --- bChapters (document)
              |
              --- //Array or Map of chapters starting with the letter b.
```

In this way, you'll be able to store 26 MiB of data, which is pretty much.

Comment: Ok very complete thanks ! Is this good too if I put read chapters in a subcollection in the user document ?

Comment: Yes, you can also do it that way, too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create such field for users collection. For example, creating "read chapters" named field (readed is not grammatically correct) which is an array, accepting String. If a user read, then you add this chapter's name to this user's doc(to "read chapters" field I mean). So you can check like that, `array.contains("chapter_name")` and mark the chapter as read or unread. That is all.

Comment: Thanks I will try it ! For now I don't have much chapter, but in the futur, I will have 10.000 chapters. Is this way will be the most optimized ? (sorry for the grammar, french here)

Comment: Yes, it is the most optimal way. Actually I am surprising, why you didn't mark my answer as accepted. But the answer which was given after me is accepted by you. If we compare, the way I suggested is better, because it takes less memory, because we only store read chapters for each user. According to the answer, that you accepted, we will have to store all chapters, regardless it is read or not.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. The first part of the other answer is the same as yours because with dont store every chapter in a list but only those who are read by the user. For me, the answer I mark is more complet, and take care of 1MB limitation and can help other user in differents ways. Nevertheless, your answer is still useful !